# Add Multiple Header Rows to pageBlockTable

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable

I have a pageBlockTable similar to the structure below. Is it possible to add another header row to the table? I attempted duplicating the existing header lines but that did not work. As a workaround, is it possible to add a new line to the text of the existing header row?

```
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!temp}" var="temp" id="temp_table">
<apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header">
        <apex:outputText value="Header1"></apex:outputText>
    </apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText value="1"/>
</apex:column>
    <apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header">
        <apex:outputText value="Header1"></apex:outputText>
    </apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText value="2"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header">
        <apex:outputText value="Header1"></apex:outputText>
    </apex:facet>
        <apex:outputText value="3"/>
    </apex:column>
```

Comment: How did you try that? Duplicating the whole `facet` or just the `outputText`? It seems like the latter should work.

Comment: I tried both and neither worked.

Comment: you can use html table and use pageblockTable css for displaying like pageblockTable

Comment: did you try adding a facet name="header" as a descendent of pageBlockTable?

Comment: @crop1645 I tried this and it works but it spans the entire table. Ideally I would have a column in the header for each column in the body of the table.

Comment: You can certainly make individual column headers multi-line using `<p>` tags inside of the column's header facet.  Then use css to style line spacing, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried and it is working.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lstAccRecords}" var="item" first="{!intPBTFirst}">
     <apex:column >
       <apex:facet name="header">
          <apex:outputPanel >
             <apex:outputText value="Header1"></apex:outputText><br/>
             <apex:outputText value="Header2"></apex:outputText>
          </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:facet>
        {!item.name}
   </apex:column>
   <apex:column value="{!item.Rating}" />
```

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lstAccRecords}" var="item" first="{!intPBTFirst}">
    <apex:column >
       <apex:facet name="header" >
          <apex:outputText escape="false" value="Header1 <br/> Header2"></apex:outputText>
       </apex:facet>
       {!item.name}
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column value="{!item.Rating}" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

both examples are working

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is the best solution but hopefully it works for you.

```
<apex:facet name="header">
    <apex:outputText escape="false" value="Header 1</br> Header 2"></apex:outputText> 
</apex:facet>
```

Notice that I just put escape="false" in outputtext and .It does display two lines.